# Incorrect time calculation with mktime to get UTC+8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ctime

I want to get the current time in Hong Kong (UTC+8), and my local time is UTC-5.

Using  and running the following in VS2012:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
char buffer[10];
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);
strftime(buffer, 10, "%H:%M:%S", localtime(&rawtime));
cout << "LocalTime=" << buffer << endl;
strftime(buffer, 10, "%H:%M:%S", gmtime(&rawtime));
cout << "GMTime=" << buffer << endl;
tm* r = gmtime(&rawtime);
r->tm_hour += 8; // Hong Kong time
mktime(r); // Normalize the struct
strftime(buffer, 10, "%H:%M:%S", r);
cout << "HongKongTime=" << buffer << endl;
```

Produces the following output:

```
LocalTime=22:51:47
GMTime=02:51:47
HongKongTime=11:51:47
```

So it's computing UTC correctly, but then adding 8 hours to that is actually producing a time that is UTC **+9**.  What's going wrong?

And is there a more elegant/reliable way of getting UTC+8 than this kludge?

Comment: First thing that an go wrong is DST (daylight saving time). There is a better way? I am curious to see answers by myself...

Comment: Yeah, DST was my first guess, but it's getting UTC correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `localtime` after changing the `TZ` environment variable to your desired timezone:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

    _putenv_s( "TZ", "GMT-08:00" );

    time_t mytime = time( NULL );
    struct tm* mytm = localtime( &mytime );

    std::cout << "Current local time and date: " << asctime(mytm);
    return 0;
}
```

The object `mytime` will receive as a result of the function `time()` the amount of seconds since `00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC`, which is the current Unix timestamp. `localtime()` will use the value pointed by `mytime` to fill a `tm` structure with the values that represent the corresponding time, expressed for the local timezone.

By default, the timezone used by `localtime()` is generally the one used in your computer. However, you can change it with the function `_putenv_s()`, in which I manipulated the `TZ` variable and added a new definition to it `GMT-08:00` which is the timezone for Hong Kong.

> In POSIX systems, a user can specify the time zone by means of the TZ
>   environment variable.

Note that however a more standard way of manipulating `TZ` variable is by using the function `int setenv (const char *name, const char *value, int replace)` but it wasn't defined in this sample, so I used an alternative.

You can read more about TZ environment variable [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html)

Comment: Wow, very elegant!  I don't quite see why this works, since Hong Kong is 8 hours _ahead_ of GMT, but your code does work.  Thank you!